Can't reopen table: 'lc1' in mysql
Please check my SP Below in mysql:
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_calculate_license_fees()
BEGIN
    DECLARE totalRowCount INT;

    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

    -- Step 1: Create LicenseChainTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS LicenseChainTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LicenseChainTemp AS
    WITH RECURSIVE LicenseChain AS (
        SELECT 
            id, citizen_id, trade_license_no, previous_license_no, fiscal_year, license_fee, signboard_fee, is_paid, applicant_name
        FROM 
            trade_license_request_uat
        WHERE 
            previous_license_no IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            t.id, t.citizen_id, t.trade_license_no, t.previous_license_no, t.fiscal_year, t.license_fee, t.signboard_fee, t.is_paid, t.applicant_name
        FROM 
            trade_license_request_uat t
        INNER JOIN 
            LicenseChain lc ON lc.trade_license_no = t.previous_license_no
    )
    SELECT * FROM LicenseChain;

    -- Step 2: Create LatestLicenseTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS LatestLicenseTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LatestLicenseTemp AS
    SELECT 
        lc1.citizen_id, 
        lc1.trade_license_no AS latest_trade_license_no,
        lc1.applicant_name
    FROM 
        LicenseChainTemp lc1
    LEFT JOIN 
        LicenseChainTemp lc2 ON lc1.trade_license_no = lc2.previous_license_no
    WHERE 
        lc2.trade_license_no IS NULL;

    -- Step 3: Create FiscalYearsTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS FiscalYearsTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE FiscalYearsTemp AS
    SELECT DISTINCT fiscal_year
    FROM trade_license_request_uat
    WHERE fiscal_year BETWEEN '2018' AND '2024';

    -- Step 4: Create ApplicantDataTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ApplicantDataTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ApplicantDataTemp AS
    SELECT 
        lc.citizen_id, lc.trade_license_no, lc.fiscal_year, lc.license_fee, lc.signboard_fee, lc.is_paid, lc.applicant_name
    FROM 
        LicenseChainTemp lc;

    -- Step 5: Create MissingYearsTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS MissingYearsTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MissingYearsTemp AS
    SELECT ay.citizen_id, ay.trade_license_no, ay.fiscal_year
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT tlr.citizen_id, tlr.trade_license_no, fy.fiscal_year
        FROM FiscalYearsTemp fy
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT citizen_id, trade_license_no FROM LicenseChainTemp) tlr
    ) ay
    LEFT JOIN ApplicantDataTemp ad ON ay.citizen_id = ad.citizen_id AND ay.fiscal_year = ad.fiscal_year AND ay.trade_license_no = ad.trade_license_no
    WHERE ad.fiscal_year IS NULL AND ay.fiscal_year BETWEEN '2018' AND '2024';

    -- Step 6: Create ApplicantFeeTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ApplicantFeeTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ApplicantFeeTemp AS
    SELECT md.citizen_id, md.trade_license_no, md.fiscal_year,
           COALESCE(ad.license_fee, (
               SELECT license_fee
               FROM ApplicantDataTemp ad2
               WHERE ad2.citizen_id = md.citizen_id
               AND ad2.trade_license_no = md.trade_license_no
               AND ad2.fiscal_year = (
                   SELECT MAX(ad3.fiscal_year)
                   FROM ApplicantDataTemp ad3
                   WHERE ad3.citizen_id = ad2.citizen_id
                   AND ad3.trade_license_no = ad2.trade_license_no
                   AND ad3.fiscal_year < md.fiscal_year
               )
           )) AS license_fee,
           COALESCE(ad.signboard_fee, (
               SELECT signboard_fee
               FROM ApplicantDataTemp ad2
               WHERE ad2.citizen_id = md.citizen_id
               AND ad2.trade_license_no = md.trade_license_no
               AND ad2.fiscal_year = (
                   SELECT MAX(ad3.fiscal_year)
                   FROM ApplicantDataTemp ad3
                   WHERE ad3.citizen_id = ad2.citizen_id
                   AND ad3.trade_license_no = ad2.trade_license_no
                   AND ad3.fiscal_year < md.fiscal_year
               )
           )) AS signboard_fee
    FROM MissingYearsTemp md
    LEFT JOIN ApplicantDataTemp ad ON md.citizen_id = ad.citizen_id AND md.fiscal_year = ad.fiscal_year AND md.trade_license_no = ad.trade_license_no;

    -- Step 7: Create CombinedFeeTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS CombinedFeeTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CombinedFeeTemp AS
    SELECT citizen_id, trade_license_no, fiscal_year, license_fee, signboard_fee
    FROM (
        SELECT citizen_id, trade_license_no, fiscal_year, 
               CASE 
                   WHEN is_paid = 2 THEN 0 
                   ELSE license_fee 
               END AS license_fee,
               CASE 
                   WHEN is_paid = 2 THEN 0 
                   ELSE signboard_fee 
               END AS signboard_fee
        FROM ApplicantDataTemp
        UNION ALL
        SELECT citizen_id, trade_license_no, fiscal_year, license_fee, signboard_fee
        FROM ApplicantFeeTemp
    ) AS fees;

    -- Step 8: Create SummarizedDataTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS SummarizedDataTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SummarizedDataTemp AS
    SELECT 
        af.citizen_id,
        af.trade_license_no,
        SUM(CASE WHEN af.fiscal_year BETWEEN '2018' AND '2023' THEN af.license_fee ELSE 0 END) AS due_for_2018_to_2023,
        SUM(CASE WHEN af.fiscal_year = '2024' THEN af.license_fee ELSE 0 END) AS due_2024_license_fee,
        SUM(CASE WHEN af.fiscal_year = '2024' THEN af.signboard_fee ELSE 0 END) AS due_2024_signboard_fee
    FROM CombinedFeeTemp af
    GROUP BY af.citizen_id, af.trade_license_no;

    -- Step 9: Create ReceivedDataTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ReceivedDataTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ReceivedDataTemp AS
    SELECT 
        tlr.citizen_id,
        tlr.trade_license_no,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fiscal_year = '2024' AND is_paid = 2 THEN license_fee ELSE 0 END) AS received_for_2024_license_fee,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fiscal_year = '2024' AND is_paid = 2 THEN signboard_fee ELSE 0 END) AS received_for_2024_signboard_fee
    FROM trade_license_request_uat tlr
    WHERE fiscal_year = '2024'
    GROUP BY tlr.citizen_id, tlr.trade_license_no;

    -- Step 10: Create FinalDataTemp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS FinalDataTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE FinalDataTemp AS
    SELECT 
        ld.citizen_id,
        ld.latest_trade_license_no AS trade_license_no,
        ld.applicant_name,
        COALESCE(sd.due_for_2018_to_2023, 0) AS due_for_2018_to_2023,
        COALESCE(sd.due_2024_license_fee, 0) AS due_2024_license_fee,
        COALESCE(sd.due_2024_signboard_fee, 0) AS due_2024_signboard_fee,
        COALESCE(rd.received_for_2024_license_fee, 0) AS received_for_2024_license_fee,
        COALESCE(rd.received_for_2024_signboard_fee, 0) AS received_for_2024_signboard_fee
    FROM 
        LatestLicenseTemp ld
    LEFT JOIN 
        SummarizedDataTemp sd ON ld.citizen_id = sd.citizen_id AND ld.latest_trade_license_no = sd.trade_license_no
    LEFT JOIN 
        ReceivedDataTemp rd ON ld.citizen_id = rd.citizen_id AND ld.latest_trade_license_no = rd.trade_license_no;

    -- Step 11: Select the final data
    SELECT 
        fd.citizen_id,
        fd.trade_license_no,
        fd.applicant_name,
        fd.due_for_2018_to_2023,
        fd.due_2024_license_fee,
        fd.due_2024_signboard_fee,
        fd.received_for_2024_license_fee,
        fd.received_for_2024_signboard_fee
    FROM 
        FinalDataTemp fd;

   

END$$

DELIMITER ;

Trying to get due and receivable for my reporting purpose.
This procedure uses intermediate tables to store the results of subqueries, which helps avoid referencing the same temporary table multiple times in a query. This approach should resolve the "Can't reopen table" error and ensure the procedure executes correctly.
But still Getting Error: Can't reopen table: 'lc1'. How can i solve this?

You use temporary table and try to use it twice in the query whereas the Reference Manual # TEMPORARY Table Problems explicitly tells:

You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.

Possible solutions:

Use static table instead of temporary one.

Of course you'd have a problem with concurrent execution, because statis table is global object and it is not local for a connection. Also you'd drop this table explicitly.
You may generate random table name in the procedure and use dynamic SQL, of course.

Use CTE based on this temporary table:

WITH 
temp_table_copy AS (
    TABLE temp_table
    )
SELECT ...
FROM temp_table      AS temp_table_copy_0         -- single-used temptable
JOIN temp_table_copy AS temp_table_copy_1 ON ...  -- additional CTE copies
JOIN temp_table_copy AS temp_table_copy_2 ON ...
...

CTE can be used in the query multiple times, rather than temporary table.
